# Regex for text before a comma within double brackets

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract text that is not only inside of double brackets but also before a comma. I have only been able to solve the two issues separately (I think) but can't figure out how to bring it together

```
Double brackets: """\[\[(.+?)\]\]*"""

Before comma: """([^,]+)"""
```

Comment: `(?<=\[\[)(.+?)(?=[,\]]+)` should do. Also, can you please add examples of text and their desired matches?

Comment: I actually also need to eliminate double brackets with ":"
Examples:
[[help]] [[7:30]] [[portland,oregon]]

The regex should get: help portland

Answer (score 0):

I think you definitely need to escape the `[]`:

`\[\[(.+?)\]\]*`

If it needs to be before a comma as well, can't you use:

`(\[\[(.+?)]]*,)`

I might be missing something here. Sorry.